# In Material-UI v5, should I prefer the css prop over the sx prop or vice versa?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, emotion

I believe these two props both use emotion under the hood and they seem to do much the same thing. I've been using the css prop because I prefer template tags and real css vs. javascript style names for css properties. Is there any reason to prefer one over the other given that they are basically interchangeable in terms of functionality?

Answer (score 7):

I read the page about the new MUI styles system here: https://next.material-ui.com/system/basics/

And it feels to me that the main difference is the following:

1. The `css` prop lets you write something that looks like classic css, as you would do in actual CSS, or Less/Sass, or styled-components
2. The `sx` prop gives access to the 'system' which is a set of utilities to quickly access props with shortcuts, as well as theme properties, which already existed before `v5`, but are now even easier to use.... after some learning curve...

The above documentation page gives a lot of examples.

Answer (score 0):

Emotion has a `css` method, see [link](https://emotion.sh/docs/@emotion/css). There is an option in `css` method to access the MUI theme object, as described [here](https://duncanleung.com/accessing-material-ui-theme-object-emotion-styled-component-css-prop/#emotion-css-string-styles---access-theme-object). The main advantage of css prop over sx, is that you can use scss styles for basic HTML elements, not only MUI components. I found this very promising as I don't want myself to lock inside MUI system that much.

In my codebase I use theme context a lot, because of light / dark palettes. For demonstration, this is my code.

```js
import { Theme, css } from '@emotion/react'

 const getButtonStyles = (theme: Theme) =>
      css({
        width: 'max-content',
        height: 24,
        minWidth: '24px',
        padding: 0,
        color: theme.palette.mode === 'light' ? 
theme.palette.grey[800] : theme.palette.grey[200],
        '&>svg': {
          verticalAlign: 'middle',
        },
      })

  const Component = () => {
    return ( <button css={getButtonStyles}><svg ... /></button> 
  )}
```

To enable css prop in your repository, you need to add this line to `tsconfig.json`:

```
"compilerOptions": { "jsxImportSource": "@emotion/react" }
```

To connect emotion theme with MUI theme in order to enable typescript types & autocomplete, you need to create a file `emotion.d.ts` with this content:

```
import { Theme as MuiTheme } from '@mui/material'

declare module '@emotion/react' {
  export interface Theme extends MuiTheme {}
}
```